# I need to find posts that contain YouTube links without http:// or https:// prefix and add http:// to all of them

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to do this via WordPress Dashboard or PhpMyAdmin at once?

For example:

```
Find this: 
youtube.com/watch?v=ycbjSLCaMXw

Replace to this:
http://youtube.com/watch?v=ycbjSLCaMXw
```

There is hundreds of them.

**Edit:** I found this line on PhpMyAdmin but I don't know how to use it.

[image: PMA Search Screen]

And there is no "operator" dropdown in "Find and Replace" screen.

[image: Find and Replace]

Comment: WP CLI search replace would be the best option here, but is this just the post content field? Or are you using custom page builders or plugins like ACF that store things in post meta?

Comment: @TomJNowell this is just for post content field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to do a little PHP work and SQL-ing.  As you might know, WordPress [stores data in a database](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-wordpress-database-management-with-phpmyadmin/)---and that database has multiple tables, each of which has several fields.  You first have to know in what specific field(s) in which specific table(s) that *youtube* content resides.  When you know where it is, then you can replace it.  You can't search for content if you don't have some general idea where it is.  For example, suppose you know that these URLs are in the `post_content` field of the `posts` table.  That's where you'd look.

After you figure out where you want to look, then you can come up with a plan on how to do the work.  I'll continue with my example where I am looking in the `post_content` field of the `posts` table.  My plan includes ensuring that all my *youtube* strings are prefixed the same, so I'll have to do a [search and replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) over all records that contain a *youtube.com/* string in their `post_content` field.

For each record, I will first remove all *www* prefixes from strings that contain *//www.youtube.com/*.  This will make all my *youtube* strings look something like this:  *...//youtube.com/...*.  Then, I will do the same thing on *https://* prefixes by replacing them with *http://* on all *http://youtube.com/* strings.  This will ensure that the only *youtube* strings that exist look something like this:  *http://youtube.com/...*; and *youtube.com/...*.

Next, my plan would include prefixing all *youtube* strings with *http://*.  This will result in *youtube* strings looking something like this:  *http://http://youtube.com/...*; and *http://youtube.com/...*.  Not a big deal, because the next part of my plan calls for changing all the double *http://* prefixes to just a single *http://* making all my *youtube* strings look like this:  *http://youtube.com/...*.  Tada!  (That's what you want, right?)

So, here's my "search-and-destroy" code for that.  (I have described what each line does with a comment above that line of code so you can cross-reference it with my explanation above.)

```
// Get the object that can do WordPress database searches.
global $wpdb;

// Select records from the "posts" table where its "post_content" field contains "youtube.com/", and return all columns (*) for each of those records.
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_content LIKE '%youtube.com/%' ");

// Iterate over each $record of the results
foreach($results as $record) {

    // Grab the string saved in post_content and put it in a variable we can manipulate.
    $str = $record->post_content;

    // Remove "www" from youtube strings
    $str = str_replace('www.youtube.com/', 'youtube.com/', $str);

    // Replace "https://" with "http://"
    $str = str_replace('https://youtube.com/', 'http://youtube.com/', $str);

    // Prepend the "http://"
    $str = str_replace('youtube.com/', 'http://youtube.com/', $str);

    // Replace the double "http://http://" with the single "http://"
    $str = str_replace('http://http://youtube.com/', 'http://youtube.com/', $str);

    // Save the manipulated string back into the database with the pretty youtube strings.
    $record->post_content = $str;
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'           => $record->ID,
        'post_content' => $str,
    ));

}
```

A final thought:  if you put this code in your **functions.php** file of [your template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/), it will run every time the file is included in the WordPress process, which is not ideal.  So you should run the above code block once (by loading a page) then immediately remove (delete) the code block.

But, wouldn't it be nice to be able to just leave this code in your template somewhere and run it, say, once every 24-hours until the end of time without having to think about it (just in case more *youtube* strings need formatting in the future)?  You could do this by putting the above code inside a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) which would initially run the code, then set a timer and run it again upon that timer's expiration?  After all, it is expensive to query the database.  If I were doing this, I would use the [after_setup_theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/after_setup_theme/) hook and run the code once every 24-hours by setting a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API).  Check this out:

```
// Whenever WordPress fires the "after_setup_theme" hook (which is pretty much on every page load), execute the block of code.
add_action('after_setup_theme', function() {

    // Only run our "search-and-destory" code if our transient expired
    if( !get_transient('_numanCebi_timer') ) {

        // Our "search-and-destroy" code goes here ...

        // Set a transient to expire after 24-hours so this code block is not entered again for a day.
        set_transient( '_numanCebi_timer', TRUE, DAY_IN_SECONDS );

    }

});
```

**Update (6/14):**  The edits to your question are not *WordPress* related, and therefore are not germane in this forum; do not expect the updated question related to *PhpMyAdmin* to be answered here.  Looks like what you found is a search tool in the *PhpMyAdmin* graphical user interface.  As shown in your first screenshot, use *%* as a wildcard to search the records (which your screenshot shows you don't have in your *youtube.com/* query). Next, there is no "operator" in a search and replace ("search-and-destroy") operation.  It simply finds the string specified and replaces it with another specified string.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But I have a question. Should I run your "search-and-destroy" code on PhpMyAdmin or functions.php? P.S. Since yesterday, there won't be youtube links without http:// preset.

Comment: *PhpMyAdmin* is a graphical user interface that allows you to manipulate the database by pointing and clicking a mouse.  The code above is PHP code that needs to be executed directly on the server (as opposed to pointing and clicking).  So, you'll have to make WordPress pull it in at run-time by placing it in a file that will be executed by the WordPress interpreter (like a template's *functions.php* file).

By the way, if you like my answer, please up-vote it and mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I edited and add images to the question. Can you please check it out.

Comment: Updated my answer for you.

Comment: I used your plan with "Better Search Replace" plug-in and that's it. Problem solved! Almost 5k posts were edited successfully.